# How to unreport bad GRE Math Subject Scores?

Tags: graduate-admissions, gre

I am a Masters Graduate in mathematics from India and I am applying for the Fall 2023 Math PhD program. I gave my GRE Math subject exam and my score is 620 (40th percentile). After reading from various online sources I realize that it is not a good score. My official score report will be sent to certain universities.

If I don't mention my GRE Subject test scores in their application form is there any chance the universities won't take my scores into consideration ?

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE. You may want to to check out our [help]; we're a little different than other sites. In particular, we are looking for general questions that others could potentially have in the future -- so, better not to list the super-specific details such as the particular universities you applied to. We don't need those kinds of details, and many question-askers soon regret providing them. I've taken a stab at cleaning up your post.

Comment: Question: You say you already sent the score reports to certain universities. Are you asking about whether you can get those universities to ignore your scores? Or are you asking whether other universities will be aware of the scores?

Comment: @cag51 While registering for the exam you get to send your official scores to 4 universities for free. So 4 universities I mentioned are already going to receive my score reports. You also unofficialy report your scores in the college application form. What I wanted to know was that of i don't mention my scores in the application form is there any chance they can be ignored by the university who will receive my official scores.